# Box-Shadow not carrying out Transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, box-shadow

I know this may be a dupe, but I'm willing to take the hit as I feel confident I have researched multiple solutions.

I have tried many methods to get This box-shadow transition to work, including:

- Switching between hex, rgb, and rgba colors in the `box-shadow` declaration.
- Using selectors with more specificity.
- Changing the the `transition` property to include `ease-in-out` at the end of the declaration.
- I cleansed the CSS file of any `transition` properties that could possibly effect the element.
- All the while, triple checking my spelling mistakes.

The inspector says my styles are not being overridden. Here is my code:

```
.site-header .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item a {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 14px rgb(0,0,0) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 14px rgb(0,0,0) inset;
  -o-box-shadow: 3px 3px 14px rgb(0,0,0) inset;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 14px rgb(0,0,0) inset;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 3s;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 3s;
  -o-transition: box-shadow 3s;
  transition: box-shadow 3s;
}

.site-header .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item a:hover{
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 14px rgb(0,0,0);
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 14px rgb(0,0,0);
  -o-box-shadow: 3px 3px 14px rgb(0,0,0);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 14px rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

What could be happening here to cause this to do nothing?

[Here is a link to my site](http://firemanrecords.com/) for an in context experience. It's the header menu in the top right corner of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
.site-header .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item a {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 3px 3px 14px rgb(0,0,0) inset;
  transition: box-shadow 3s;
}

.site-header .genesis-nav-menu .menu-item a:hover {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 14px rgb(0,0,0), 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0) inset;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use transition: all; instead of box-shadow, should fix your issue